# $U$ is a continuous random variable $R.V$ uniformly distributed over $[-2, 3]$. Let $R.V$ $G=U^2$. Find $f_G(g)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Please help me in verifying whether have I solved the following problem correctly or not. If no kindly guide me.

Let $U$ is a continuous random variable $R.V$  uniformly distributed over $[-2, 3]$.
Define new $R.V$

$G=U^2$

find $f_G(g)$

My attempt:

$f_U(u) = 0.2$

$F_U(u)= 0.2U$

Now we have:

$F_G(g) = Pr(G<=g) = Pr(U^2<=g)=Pr(\sqrt{-g}<U<\sqrt{g})= F_U(\sqrt{g})-F_U(\sqrt{-g})= 2/5*(\sqrt{g})$

Hence :
$f_G(g) = 2/(10*\sqrt{g})$

Answer (score 0):

$G$ takes values in $(0,9)$. $P(U^{2}\leq g)=P(-2,<U<3, -\sqrt g \leq U \leq \sqrt g)$. This is $\frac 2 5 \sqrt g$ only when $0 <g <4$. For $4<g<9$ we get $\frac 1  5 (2+\sqrt g)$. Now differentiate.

Comment: How is $U$ taking values in $(0,9)?$

Comment: @Ameer786 There was a typo. I meant to say that $G$ takes values in $(0,9)$.

Comment: Ok but still its not clear to me. since $G=U^2$  then G must be defined for $(4,9)$. How it is $(0,9)?$

Comment: Why do you think $G$ must be greater than $4$? if $U$ si close to $0$ then $U^{2}$ is also close to $0$. What we know is $U^{2} \geq 0$ and $U^{2} \leq \max \{(-2)^{2}, 3^{2}\}=9$.  @Ameer786

Comment: I think $G$ must be greater than $4$ is because $G=U^2$ and $U$ is defined for $(-2,3).$ Hence G must be defined for $((-2)^2,3^2) = (4,9)$...Also How $U$ is close to $0$ I don't get your point. Please elaborate further

Comment: You have to find the possible values for $t^{2}$ when $t$ lies between $-2$ and $3$, Is it not clear that $0^{2}=0$ so $0$ is a possible value? @Ameer786